# Visual Studio 2010: Predefined Namespaces

Tags: visual-studio-2010, namespaces, installation

I just want to know if it's possible to put additional namespaces as soon as I create a new item (e.g. Web Form)

Default (predefined) namespaces:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
```

I would like to add

```
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Data;
```

as predefined namespaces.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

please check in the following link :

http://www.rhyous.com/2010/02/17/how-to-modify-the-default-new-class-template-in-visual-studio-2008/